# Select random paragraph from list

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript, and I'd like to create my own Lorem Ipsum generator.

Basically, I would have a list of the paragraphs (in javascript, or in the HTML document?).

When the user presses the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button, it would then output 3 random paragraphs from the list.

I've looked around on here, but can't really find anything that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try looking around on Google?

Comment: Do you have any code? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I did look around on the Great Google, but all I've managed to come up with is to simpley print a statement when I click the button (part of the W3C tutorial)

Comment: I don't think this is worth of an actual answer, but here's some jQuery/JS that will pick one of the paragraphs at random without repeating any paragraph: http://jsfiddle.net/WLd6L/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply have a Javascript Array and pick a random index and inject that paragraph into the DOM element.  I've also updated the code to not repeat the previous random integer per your comment below.

**Example (code untested)**

```
//global to store previous random int
_oldInt = null;

var paragraphArray = ["Lorem ipsum delor...", "The great white...", "Chitty-chitty-bang-bang..."];  

//update element content (e.g. `<div>` with paragraph)
document.getElementById("MyID").innerHTML = pickRandom(paragraphArray);

var pickRandom = function(paragraphArray){
    //random index of paragraphArray
    var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*paragraphArray.length);
    //ensure random integer isn't the same as last
    if(randomInt == _oldInt)
        pickRandom(paragraphArray);
    else{
        _oldInt = randomInt;
        return paragraphArray[randomInt];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks very much! However, you were missing an equals sign between innerHTML and (randomParagraph) apparently. Once I added that, it worked. Thanks for the push in the right direction :)

Comment: You are most welcome.  I've edited this post w/ your input thx.

Comment: Regarding your edit - the script works regardless of whether the aforementioned randomParagraph has brackets around it. Is that normal?

Comment: Well, 'document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = (randomParagraph);' has the same result as 'document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomParagraph;'

Comment: One more question - what can I do to stop it selecting the same paragraph again, after clicking the Generate button? It is very random selection, of course, but it sometimes displays the same one as before, but no more than twice in a row.

Comment: Simply create a variable to store the previous integer like so... `var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*paragraphArray.length);` also create a global variable that stores the randomInt and write an `if` statement that checks if the `randomInt == oldInt` and if it does, just generate a new one.

Comment: Ok, the problem I'm having now is that I have 2 text areas. One is formatted, and the other displays the raw HTML formatting code (paragraph, list, line break etc). (Easier for web designers etc) The problem now, is that the two text areas are generating different paragraphs. With the other generation functions (that are less complicated), I'm using `document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = pickRandom(paragraphArray); document.getElementById("textarea-code").innerHTML = pickRandom("&lt;P&gt;" + paragraphArray + "&lt;&#47;P&gt;");` How do I link the two?

Comment: Create another question on SO with some HTML/CSS and Javascript and I will be able to help you there.

Comment: Also, the script still doesn't seem to acknowledge whether the same paragraph was just called. Saying that, that's happening a lot less frequently!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.random` to generate a random index from your list:

```
var paragraphs = [...]; # This is your list of paragraphs

function get_random_paragraph() {
    var index = Math.floor(paragraphs.length * Math.random());
    return paragraphs[index];
};
```

The expression `Math.floor(MAX_VALUE * Math.random())` generates a random integer `x`, where `0 <= x < MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need some `paragraphs` (here, a JavaScript array), a `result` box (here, a `<div>`) and a `button` (here, a... `<button>`).

When you click on the `button`, you want to add a `paragraphs` into the `result`.

```
var paragraphs = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
    nbParagraphs = paragraphs.length
    paragraph = null,
    result = document.getElementById('result'),
    button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    /*
     * Math.random() return a number between 0 and 1
     * parseInt() return an integer (the 10 is here to say that we are in decimal)
     * parseInt(Math.random() * nbParagraphs, 10) return a number between 0 and the number of paragraphs, so we can use it to select a paragraph in the paragraphs array
     */
    paragraph = paragraphs[parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * nbParagraphs, 10))]
    result.innerHTML += '<p>' + paragraph + '</p>'
})
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/dckXv/1/).